# css div alignment top

Tags: css, html

My code:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1>Hello.</h1>
</div>
<div id="welcome" >
<a href="/eciepecie">Login</a>
</div></div>

#welcome{
color: #333333;
font-size: 90%;
float: right;
text-align: right;
padding-right: 30px;
}
#header{
padding: 10px 20px;
width: 400px;
}
#header h1 {
line-height:20px;
float: left;
background: #ffffff url('../img/hello.png') no-repeat left;
color: #222222;
padding: 0px 30px;
}
```

I wish both divs (header and welcome) to be "aligned top" but they aren't, ->left one #header is above left div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `<h1>` tag around "Hello." and made the following changes:

```
#welcome{
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#header{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}
```

The `<h1>` tag typically has predefined padding and other properties that can throw off things like spacing.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4SpX7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Put `float: left;` on both of them.

Comment: then both of them are aligned to left while i want one in right, one in left and aligned top. (left one is "bigger = higher") while right is smaller and they are aligned to bottom instead of top.